# openxml merge documents using altChunk and use destination paragraph format

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I have a template.docx, doc1.docx, doc2.docx. I am trying to merge doc1.docx and doc2.docx into template.docx using altChunk. The 3 documents have different font size and font styles. I want the resulting document base on the style in template.docx. Any ideas how to achieve that?

For example:

1. all the heading1 font size is 24, font color is blue
2. List paragraph font size is 12, font family is Times New Roman